# Running async method in constructor stops ObservableCollection showing data

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

I've got an issue when calling an async method in a constructor. It stops data ever showing in an `ObservableCollection` even though I can see it in debug when I trace through the code. To work around the issue I have a non async version of the same method but obviously this is not ideal. How can I get my async method to work properly in a constructor?

If I call `this.RefreshCarList("")` in the constructor of `MainWindowViewModel` then subsequent calls to `this.RefreshCarListAsync("")` (not from within the constructor) will work perfectly fine and data shows on the screen. If I only call `this.RefreshCarListAsync("")` then data never shows.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Car> carList;
    public ICollectionView CarList { get; private set; }
    private DataReceivedHandler dataReceivedHandler = new DataReceivedHandler();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //this.RefreshCarList(""); // Gets data on startup
        this.RefreshCarListAsync("") // Doesn't show any data
        this.CarList = new QueryableCollectionView(this.carList, typeof(Car));
    }

    public void RefreshCarList(string carBrand)
    {
        this.carList = this.dataReceivedHandler.GetCarList(carBrand);
    }

    public async Task RefreshCarListAsync(string carBrand)
    {
        this.carList = await this.dataReceivedHandler.GetCarListAsync(carBrand);
    }
}
```

The view model uses a data receiver class which gets data from a service:

```
public class DataReceivedHandler
{
    private CarDataService dataService = new CarDataService();
    private List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
    private ObservableCollection<Car> carOC = new ObservableCollection<Car>();


    public ObservableCollection<Car> GetCarList(string carBrand)
    {
        carListFromService = this.dataService.GetCarList(carBrand);
        this.carOC.Clear();
        foreach (ICar car in carListFromService)
            this.carOC.Add(car);
        

        return (this.carOC);
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Car>> GetCarListAsync(string carBrand)
    {
        carListFromService = await Task.Run(() => this.dataService.GetCarList(carBrand)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        this.carOC.Clear();
        foreach (ICar car in carListFromService)
            this.carOC.Add(car);

        return (this.carOC);
    }
}
```

The service:

```
public class CarDataService
{
    private List<Car> CarList = new CarList();
    public List<Car> GetCarList(string carBrand)
    {
        return this.CarList;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

So I've tried this as one of the answers suggested, however it still doesn't work:

```
public async Task Initialise()
{
    try
    {
        await this.CarListAsync("");
        this.CarList = new QueryableCollectionView(this.carList, typeof(Car));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

this.viewModel.Initialise(); // in a different class
```

Comment: Calling an async method in a constructor doesn't make sense to me. It would allow you to use the object before the constructor had finished potentially, this is likely your issue.  Why does it have to be async?

Comment: You must not make any async call from a constructor. Consider exposing a `public async Task Initialize()` method that is called and awaited *after* construction.

Comment: Does `this.CarListAsync("")` not return a value - which should not be ignored? Something like `carList = await CarListAsync("");`?

Comment: Also, `this.viewModel.Initialise();` should be `await viewModel.Initialise();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is being set dynamically after the constructor has returned, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in your `MainWindowViewModel` class:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICollectionView  carList;
    public ICollectionView  CarList
    {
        get { return carList; }
        private set { carList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private DataReceivedHandler dataReceivedHandler = new DataReceivedHandler();

    public async Task Initialise()
    {
        try
        {
            await this.CarListAsync("");
            this.CarList = new QueryableCollectionView(this.carList, typeof(Car));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: this errors with cannot implicitly convert type ObservableCollection to ICollectionView

Comment: Well, that's your code. Change the field to `ICollectionView` then. Or the other way around.

Comment: The point is that you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you @mm8

Answer (score 0):

Note that `this.carList` is initialized in `RefreshCarListAsync`:

```
this.carList = await this.dataReceivedHandler.GetCarListAsync(carBrand);
```

But it potentially gets initialized not right away but later, when `GetCarListAsync` provides the result. Then in constructor you do not await `RefreshCarListAsync` (you can't do that in constructor anyway):

```
this.RefreshCarListAsync("") // Doesn't show any data
```

Because you do not await - the next statement

```
this.CarList = new QueryableCollectionView(this.carList, typeof(Car));
```

executes (potentially) *before* `this.carList` is initialized. So `this.carList` is null when that line executes, most likely leading to your problem.

So, IF you are going to do that from constructor, you need to do something like:

```
private async Task Initialize() {
    try {
          await this.RefreshCarListAsync("") // Doesn't show any data
          this.CarList = new QueryableCollectionView(this.carList, typeof(Car));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
         // do something meaningful, otherwise it will go unnoticed
    }
}
```

And call that from constructor. Or better - make it public and don't call it from constructor but let whatever uses your viewmodel to call it, since there is a chance it might be able to await it.

Comment: Calling `Initialize()` from a constructor is also bad. It should be awaited and you can't do that in a constructor. Anything async does not belong there.

Comment: Well that's why I added that big IF. Big chance that if not from constructor then it will be called from event handler or other place which cannot await anyway, since that's UI framework. In such case good to know that you must handle potential exception at least.

Comment: I'd just make the Initialize method public, and call and await it after construction of the view model.

Comment: @Clemens I've tried making the Initialize method public and do the code Evk suggests but it still doesn't work